# sort java list by single attribute

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream

I have a Java list of items and those items have a property. This property can be checked with a lambda resulting in `true` or `false`. Now I want to sort this list to have all the elements with that property in the front, and all the others in the back.

My current approach is

```java
List<String> frontIds = ... // contains the ids of the items, that I want in front
List<Item> items = ... // contains all the items
List<List<Item>> sortedBy = new ArrayList<>(
  items.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(item -> frontIds.contains(item.getId()))
  ).values()
);
sortedBy.get(1).addAll(sortedBy.get(0));

// my sorted list is not sortedBy.get(1)
```

It does feel a bit bulky and unnecessary to group and create the `ArrayList`. I thought of using `items.sort`... but how would I compare just one element with the list of `frontIds`

Comment: Note that you can use `partitioningBy()` instead of `groupingBy()`.

Comment: yes, I have seen that somewhere as well, but I have a map, that I need to flatten again, right?

Comment: Yes, it's just more efficient for grouping on a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort on a boolean. But it can be a little unintuitive because `false` [precedes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#compareTo-java.lang.Boolean-) `true`, so you have to invert it:

```
List<Item> sorted = items.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(item -> !frontIds.contains(item.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort it in place just by using the `Collections.sort` helper method. Here's how it looks.

```
Collections.sort(items, Comparator.comparing(item -> !frontIds.contains(item.getId())));
```